# SQL String displaying no information

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an old website trying to re-write it totally

I have the following SQL String it works on my old site but bringing it to the new one I get no information displayed.

```
<table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="13%">&nbsp;</th>
                      <th width="13%">Cell Number</th>
                      <th width="15%">Requested By</th>
                      <th width="13%">Send to</th>
                      <th width="45%">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lbs_trace_etrack WHERE id='$id'");
?>
        <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<td><p>
                        <input name="lbs_msisdn" type="text" id="lbs_msisdn" value="<? echo $rows['lbs_msisdn']; ?>" size="12">
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <input type="text" name="lbs_station" id="lbs_station" value="<? echo $rows['lbs_station']; ?>">
                      </p>
 </td>
<?php } ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I send the id and it is in the URL as follow:

```
 iframe/retrace.php?id=39661
```

Username, Password and login details are as per normal and it logs into the DB properly.

Edited:
From the previous page I use the following button Link

```
onClick="location.href='retrace.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'"
```

Comment: What is the value of `$id`? Have you checked it?

Comment: The value should be as in the URL retrace.php?id=39661

Comment: maybe the new server doesn't support the `mysql_` api (I've my money on it). Check for errors with error reporting and on the query.

Comment: I ask again - what is the __real__ value of `$id`?

Comment: It is same server just new CSS format and new look on my site. Some of the other SQL strings mysql_

Comment: *"String it works on my old site but **bringing it to the new one** I get no information displayed."* - This tells me it's on a new server; what am I not grasping?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: u_mulder I do not understand your question as the value is part of a button link from a previous page? How else can I confirm the real value. It is sent from a button link on different page

Comment: so, where's the `$_GET['id']` ? and other related ones for the inputs. Your question is unclear on too many levels.

Comment: Ok, someone popped an answer down there. Whether you'll still see it, well....... anyway, I'll have to move on now because I don't know how to help you or where to throw myself with this; again, your question is unclear on too many levels. Wishing you well with this.

Comment: New server? I wonder if it's PHP7 and complaining about the removed `mysql_` functions.. (And now I see Fred -ii- already said that. Oops)

Comment: I am not getting any error logs at all.

Comment: Still on Ver 5.6 PHP

Comment: How are you setting `$id`?

Comment: Do you get the table and just no rows? Try echoing your query, and check for `mysql_error` after your query and when trying to get the rows.

Comment: I get the table no rows and the error msg shows no msg at all

Comment: If you echo `mysql_num_rows($result)` right after your query, what does it say?

Comment: If I Echo mysql_num_rows($result) after query I get 0

Comment: If I add the $id manually into the string it displays the data. So it is not getting the $id information from the URL if I am correct

Comment: Ok I have found the problem

Comment: Echo out the query to make sure it looks correct.

Comment: I added the following $id = $_GET['id'] ; This then pulls the id for me. Thanks to Fred-ii-

Comment: @JamesWright I posted my answer below that you can now mark as solved. Plus I did a rollback to a previous revision. and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *" I added the following $id = $_GET['id'] ; This then pulls the id for me. Thanks to Fred-ii- – James Wright 2 mins ago"*

Just as I stated in comments, the `$_GET` array `$_GET['id']` was never set or assigned a variable to it, since you're using `retrace.php?id`.

Btw, your code is open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

SQL injection:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Plus, if at all possible, consider refactoring your code to using the MySQLi_ or PDO APIs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Thanks Fred I just had to work thru all comments and test all possibilities, Appreciate your nudge in right direction

Comment: @JamesWright You're welcome James, glad to have been of help to solve the question, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

don't have comment rights yet. sorry. 
but can u check your php tags? make them all < ? php to ensure short_open_tag is not disabled. (missing the first one) post a result source of your browser.

edit: lol just edited out my $id shows in log rable becouse i saw you had $_GET['id'] in the source for a second. :P

Comment: I think you might have the right of it. `<?` was removed in 5.3.